# How to store a table of user_input(), into a named tuple

Tags: python-3.6

how can i store user input(), into a named tuple when a table like data is entered

5

ID         MARKS      NAME       CLASS
1          97         Raymond    7
2          50         Steven     4
3          91         Adrian     9
4          72         Stewart    5
5          80         Peter      6

take this input() for example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work starting Python 3.7

```
from typing import NamedTuple


class Student(NamedTuple):
    id_: int
    marks: int
    name: str
    class_: int


try:
    student = Student(*input().split())
except TypeError:
    print("error")
```

For older Pythons, you have to declare `namedtuple` in this way

```
from collections import namedtuple


Student = namedtuple('Student', ('id_', 'marks', 'name', 'class_', ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code can be used if you are looking for dynamic input of column names

```
from collections import namedtuple
n = int(input())
Tot_mark = 0

for i in range(n+1):     
    if i == 0:
        s = ",".join(input().split())
        students = namedtuple('students',s)
    else:
        a,b,c,d = input().split()
        res = students(a,b,c,d)
        Tot_mark = Tot_mark + int(res.MARKS)
    
print(round(Tot_mark/n,2))
```